# OnTouchListener being called too often in BaseAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I set an `OnTouchListener` on a `ImageView` in my `CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

The Method looks like:

```
 holder.projectImageImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context1, test.class);
            intent.putExtra("projectInfo",projectItems);
            intent.putExtra("distributorInfo", distributorItems);
            intent.putExtra("contractorInfo",contractorItems);
            context1.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

So if I have 3 Items in my `ListView` and I click on an Items `ImageView` why it get called as many Items I have?

Comment: use UP_EVENT in MotionEvent class to call intent.

Answer (score 0):

After I've change from `OnTouchListener` to `OnClickListener` it works great!